# stop user entering special characters

Tags: java

I know that the code below will prohibit the user from entering digits but how do I manipulate it to prohibit special characters, e.g. `,./;'#[]-=<>?:@~{}_+`.

```
txtUserName.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (Character.isDigit(e.getKeyChar()))
            e.consume();
   }
});
```

Comment: He will not be prohibited to enter digits, only digits are allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Code:

```
txtUserName.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
            e.consume();
   }
});
```

Just use a different function.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `",./;'#[]-=<>?:@~{}_+".indexOf(c) != -1`.

See [`String#indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29).

Comment: that works for them all except '"' because it thinks I am closing the quotations so what's the solution for that?

Comment: Escape the double quote: `",./;\"'#[]..."`.

Comment: Neither is "Better Practice" really, it just depends on preference, and which looks easier to understand, etc.

Comment: @Ethan's way is a clearer way to say "I want to allow only letters and numbers". My way is a clearer way to say "I want to allow all characters _except_ the ones I'm specifically prohibiting".